# generate script of content of one table as a .sql file(via code)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

is this possible that i create a stored procedure that generates content of defined table to a path that i passed as its(stored procedure) parameter?

Comment: You could just query the table in Management Studio, right click the results & choose Save As to save to a csv file.

Comment: he needs stored proc to do it from code etc.

Comment: By content, do you me all of the rows or the table structure?  Both are easily doable using dynamic SQL...

Comment: i want run t from stored procedure!

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
create procedure dbo.ShowAllRows (@tabName VARCHAR(200) )
as
begin
    declare @Sql    NVARCHAR(2000)
    set @Sql = 'select * FROM '+@tabName
    EXEC (@sql)
end
go
exec ShowAllRows  'sys.configurations'
```

I missed the path part, I assume you want the above type of code, with a second parameter, i.e. @outputFileName

If your SQL-server has access to the file path and you can run XP_CMDShell, you can do the following...

```
create procedure dbo.ShowAllRows (@tabName VARCHAR(200),@outPath VARCHAR(200) )
as
begin
    declare @Sql    NVARCHAR(2000)

    set @sql = 'bcp '+@tabName+' out '+@outPath+' -U<user> -P<password> '
    print @sql
    EXEC xp_cmdShell @sql
end
```

You can also use the -T for trusted connection if you don't want the user name and password in the procedure

Comment: SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell' of component 'xp_cmdshell' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'xp_cmdshell' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'xp_cmdshell'.....

Comment: also. i will run this on a shared host!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the table structure, here is the SQL to get you started...

```
select column_name,data_type,is_nullable
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = '<table name>'
order by ordinal_position
```

In a procedure, simply do

```
create produce ShowColumnsforTable( @tabName VARCHAR(200) )
as
begin
    select column_name,data_type,is_nullable
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_name = @tabName
    order by ordinal_position

end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
create proc spOutputData @tbl varchar(500)
as

declare @cmd varchar(4000)

SELECT @cmd = 'bcp ' + @tbl + ' out c:\OutFile.txt -c  -q -Shpas -T'

exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

TEST:

```
spOutputData 'master.dbo.syslogins'
```